# How to make a div stick near the top of the page on scroll?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I get the two purple buttons on this page (or rather the white parent container slide2) to stick right underneath the red header div when it hits the bottom edge of it upon scrolling?

I created this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/baumdexterous/K7NSX/

A similar example of what I'm trying to accomplish:
http://jsbin.com/ijexe

HTML:

```
<div id="container">

    <div class="menu">
        <div class="container clearfix">

            <div id="header" class="grid_12">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="slide" id="slide1">
        <div class="container clearfix">

            <div id="section1" class="grid_12">
            </div>


        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="slide" id="slide2">
        <div class="container clearfix">

            <div id="test" class="grid_6">
                <a href="" target="_blank" class="btn1"></a>
            </div>

            <div id="test" class="grid_6 omega">
                <a href="" target="_blank" class="btn2"></a>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="slide" id="slide3">
        <div class="container clearfix">

            <div id="section3" class="grid_12">
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

Check this out...... it's what you want.

**http://www.jsfiddle.net/5ADzD/1**

```
$window.scroll(function(event) {
   var scrollTop = $window.scrollTop()
   if (scrollTop >  ... )
   {
       //execute code
   }
   else
   {
       //execute other code
   } 
});
```

Comment: Nope, not quite what I was looking for. I couldn't find an example on StackOverflow yet that accomplished what I was hoping to do. Thanks though.

Comment: did you check the new link?

Comment: Hey Real Liu – thanks, I did, but the Javascript seems a bit complicated to me. Do you know if there a simple way to achieve this just targeting the element.. something like:
/* $(window).scroll(function () { if ($(window).scrollTop() > 340) { $('#slide2').......; } else { $('#slide2').......; } }); */ 

? Thanks so much.

Comment: @Ori ok hold on I'm building a simpler version.

Comment: @Ori check this jsfiddle.net/5ADzD/1

Comment: What is the purpose of setting the width in the JS?

Answer (score 0):

Try this script.

```
 var $window = $(window);
            $stickyEl = $('#youelementID');
            var elTop = $stickyEl.offset().top;
            $window.scroll(function() {
                var windowTop = $window.scrollTop();
                $stickyEl.toggleClass('sticky', windowTop > elTop);
            });
```

/// and Css

```
.sticky
{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
}
```